# Opening external program in python

Tags: python, flask, cmd, exe

So I have a new problem that's a little bit weird, I'm trying to open an external program in Flask (the program is written in C++ but compiled as a .exe file ), I can run it with cmd, I can run it with clicking on it and both of them works fine, but when I try to open them with python, the program window starts in my windows and then stops immediately I can't even see it for 1 sec.
About my C++ Program, it reads some inputs for some text file, and then create some more text file after reading.
I've already used: subprocess.call, subprocess.Popen, os.startfile, os.system.
and I know my Program address is valid, because my app start but it stops immediately. there is no error in python, no error in cmd while using os.system etc.
I would love to get any suggestions.
current code:

```
        if request.method == 'POST' and 'checkbox' in request.form:
            if request.form.get("checkbox") is not None:
                os.startfile(r"C:\Users\Administrator\flaskProject\upload\19\29\engine\engine.exe")
```

Comment: Why is `subprocess.run()` not used to run the executable as recommended by the Python documentation for the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)? The `subprocess` module is on Windows a Python wrapper for the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) with the structure [STARTUPINFO](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfow) used on Windows by any executable capable starting an executable.

Comment: Please read also the Python documentation for [os.startfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) which is not for running directly an executable, but for running an executable associated with a file extension with the file name passed as argument to the executable to open this file by the associated application. In this case is used the function [ShellExecuteEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecuteexw) with structure [SHELLEXECUTEINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-shellexecuteinfow).

Comment: In other words `os.startfile` is for opening a `.html` file in the default browser according to user configuration or a `.docx` file in the document processing application associated with that file extension. There is no executable associated to open a file with file extension `.exe`. For that reason `os.startfile` is the wrong function to run an executable like `engine.exe`.

Comment: @Mofi thanks for sharing these info, I've used subprocess.run to test it but i've got no luck. when I run subprocess.run directly from python ( without flask platform ) it works fine, but when i run the code under a app route in flask, it doesn't work and even makes my program crash. i'm thinking that there is a problem with flask and opening external files on request, but there is no info about it on internet or even on flask documentations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution for my case, I think there is a problem with Flask upload module, my C++ program was on the same path as my uploaded files from flask, so when I changed the program path and used Windows command prompt to start the program, everything worked like a charm.

Comment: In other words your C++ coded executable is obviously not good coded. It references perhaps other files which are in same directory as the `.exe` file, but your code references these files without path which means with a path relative to current directory. If `winword.exe` (Microsoft Word) would be coded as you coded your executable, nobody would be able to open a `.docx` file with a double click in Windows Explorer.

Comment: You should use in C++ code [GetModuleFileName](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulefilenamew) to get the full path of the executable and concatenate that path with each name of a file stored in same directory on opening those files. Then all files are referenced with full qualified file name and it does not longer matter which directory is the current directory of the executable.

Comment: It is also possible to use `subprocess.run()` with parameter `cwd="C:\\Users\\Administrator\\flaskProject\\upload\\19\\29\\engine"` (or any other folder path) to explicitly define the current working directory for the executable to run. The folder path could be derived from storage location of Python script file or Python executable if the Python script file is later converted to an executable.